# Getting a @formatjs/ecma402-abstract version1.3 found error: DateTimeFormat/skeleton.d.ts(4,13) ',' expected. TS1005 Error

Tags: reactjs, react-intl, formatjs

In the React project I'm using `"react-intl": "^5.6.8"` and all of sudden it started breaking when running a dev server or building, throwing an error related to the `formatjs`:

```
   /node_modules/@formatjs/ecma402-abstract/src/DateTimeFormat/skeleton.d.ts(4,13):


    2 | export declare function processDateTimePattern(pattern: string, result?: Pick<DateTimeFormatOptions, 'weekday' | 'era' | 'year' | 'month' | 'day' | 'hour' | 'minute' | 'second' | 'timeZoneName'> & {
    3 |     hour12?: boolean;
  > 4 | }): [pattern: string, pattern12: string];
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix the issue by updating TypeScript to the latest version (4.0.5)

`npm i -D typescript@latest`

The issue is still open on [github](https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/issues/2286).